# Loop over dynamic dict name pyspark

Tags: python, json, for-loop, pyspark, databricks

I have a list with the API output - json.

```
l = ['d1','d2']
```

I would like to create a loop to take the value but I have Ann error that 'strings indices must be integers'.

```
For i in l:
   Print (i.replace("'","")['value'])
```

Comment: Why does the output of an API know/rely on how you named your  variables? Seems very strange. In any case, use a dictionary to map names to values.

Comment: Each element of a list is a dict which contains different API response

Comment: If this is API response in JSON, it is a string and you should first convert it to dict with `json.loads(i)['value']`.